# jQuery UI - autocomplete error

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I'm using **jquery.ui.autocomplete and datepicker** for an implementation in my webpage.
As separate file

> - jquery.ui.datePicker.js
> - jquery.ui.autocomplete.js

With the following simple code

```
var availableTags = ["ActionScript", "AppleScript", "Asp", "BASIC", "C", "C++",
"Clojure", "COBOL", "ColdFusion", "Erlang", "Fortran", "Groovy", "Haskell",
"Java", "JavaScript", "Lisp", "Perl", "PHP", "Python", "Ruby", "Scala", "Scheme"];

$("#City").autocomplete({
        source: availableTags
});
```

However I'm not able to get it working in webpage as expected, whereas **`datepicker`** is working great.  *Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this behavior in jsfiddle.*

**Error from console:** *pointing the jquery.ui.autocomplete.js file*

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'menu'
>   **jquery.ui.autocomplete.js:185**

I've imported both js and css properly.  Please share your suggestions

> jQuery version: 1.8.2
>   jQuery UI version: 1.9.2

Comment: can u make a fiddle ?

Comment: @TusharGupta Sorry, I couldn't reproduce this behavior in jsfiddle.

Comment: @Phil The reason behind separate files is customizing.  I'm doing the customization individually.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you obtained your jQuery UI script files, but the components don't usually come in separate scripts.

The *Autocomplete* plugin depends on *Core*, *Widget*, *Position* and *Menu* which will define the `menu` plugin.

I suggest you use the entire script library, eg

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

If you insist on using separate component files, you'll also need *Core*, *Widget*, *Position* and *Menu* though I wouldn't recommend this approach.

You can customise the plugins by overwriting their implementation with your own (using prototypal inheritance) if you must but I certainly wouldn't be re-writing the source files.

Comment: +1 Though it affects other functionality, I consider this as a better chose.  Since I'm working on a existing project I can't use this.